# Reading floats from string as 2 integers

Tags: c, integer, scanf

I'm trying to read floats from string splitting them up to 2 integers.

```
sscanf(line, "%d.%d", &dec, &frac));
```

This works with strings like this:

```
"0.25"
```

But if theres an optional sign before the number, it doesn't work anymore.

```
"-0.25"
```

How can i 'tell' sscanf, that there might be an optional sign before the number?

Comment: Be careful with this strategy.. if `line` is `"-1.-2"`, `frac` ends up being negative - perhaps not what you intended.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? `-0` = `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see `%d` is fine because it is for signed integer, but the issue here comes from the fact that `-0` is `0`... You will have to find a workaround since I don't think you can find a clean and easy way for that specific case.

Comment: If you just want to print it, you can do: `if(dec == 0 && line[0] == '-') printf("-");`, then print like normal.